# How @user goes to show action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In every example for create or update action that I see, they have something like this.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Here how the `redirect_to @user` goes to show action of the controller. Can anybody explain me this?

Comment: Want me to write it simple or complicated?

Comment: In any way which might make it understandable for a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby (the language which supports Rails), you set `@instance_variables` to store data for that request. Whilst you can store many types of data in a variable, Rails often assigns `@model` objects to them...

```
@user = User.find 1
#-> @user = <User id: "1", name: "john" .... >
```

This means that whenever you use a helper (such as `redirect_to`, or even a `path_helper`), you're actually able to pass the *object* to it and Rails will extract the data it requires.

For example...

```
user_path(@user)
edit_user_path(@user)
```

In the instance of a path, the helper extracts the `id` of the object; redirect_to extrapolates the functionality to route the request to the `show` path for that user.

Passing `redirect_to` accepts an object, invoking the *show* action for that object.

---

The reason why this is important is to understand that Ruby (& by virtue Rails) is [*object orientated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Object orientated programming means that you should be dealing with *objects* (not variables).

In the case of Rails, each model should be an object. Every time you load the model, or create a new instance of it, you should be dealing with the object rather than the data.

Therefore, allowing you to pass `@objects` to methods such as `redirect_to` is just another way to make Rails more object-orientated.

Comment: Can amend or delete if required

Comment: Thanks.. This helped me understand way more than what i wanted.

Comment: Thanks buddy, much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Let's start from the [`redirect_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) documentation.

```
redirect_to post_url(@post)
```

is used to redirect to a specific URL generated using one of the Rails route helpers. In your case, it means you can write

```
redirect_to user_url(@user)
```

However, `redirect_to` also accepts a single model instance. [Behind the scenes](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2090615d39c071c9eb25e715275eb79f3f9b6266/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb#L95), `redirect_to` relies on [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html#method-i-url_for) to generate an URL from the input when the input is not an object.

`url_for`, in turns, when you pass an instance of a model by default will compute the corresponding `GET` action to view the model.

In conclusion, the following code:

```
redirect_to @post
```

is equivalent to

```
redirect_to post_url(@post)
```

However, personally I prefer the explicit version. Even if it's a little bit longer, I've noticed it tends to produce more maintainable code in the long run. Writing the full route will allow you to easily search your code base when you need to debug or rename routes.

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to).

> Record - The URL will be generated by calling url_for with the options, which will reference a named URL for that record.

So, `url_for` will be called on your `@user` which will produce the url for redirection. (`/users/1234` or something)

This is just one of many ways to do redirection, by the way.